# I get "This software was closed because an error occurred" when trying to play my game

Tags: nintendo-switch

When trying to play my game (in this case Lego City Undercover) I get

> This software was closed because an error occurred

As embarrassing as this title may be I do still want to play it :).

Comment: So, what's embarrassing about it? These games aren't made exclusively for kids but also adults that grew up with the bricks. There are many hidden jokes in their stuff kids certainly will never get. I'm 30+, own most of those Lego games and enjoyed "The Lego Movie" (the Batman one bit so much).

Comment: That was really a joke @Mario -- I think Lego games are some of my favorites! But that does not diminish the points you make!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting the console solved this problem for me.

1. Hold down the power button for a few seconds
2. Select Power Options
3. Select Restart

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi Why? It's an obvious suggestion but still less savvy users might not think about it.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi. Not only do a lot of people never think about restarting their machine, even more people *don't know how to restart the Nintendo Switch* at all. This answer is entirely justified.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this message a few times. I just loaded the game again and it played fine for me. This also happened with Lego Worlds. I didn't bother restarting the console. I just started the game again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with Super Mario Odyssey just today, and unfortunately performing a system reboot wasn't helping.  I'm going to leave this answer here in case anyone else is having the same issue.

I tried checking for corrupted data in System Settings > Data Management > Software > (Game), and it said there was indeed corrupt data, however, when I tried to "fix it" the process failed, saying it couldn't read the SD card.

Now, I'm playing the game using a physical cartridge, but I did have an SD card inserted, so perhaps some data was installed there?  I don't really know.  Anyway, I fixed it by doing the following:

1. power off device
2. remove SD card
3. power on device
4. re-download the game (with game cartridge inserted)

And then the game would launch.

Come to think of it, my wife and I have also been getting "corrupt data" warnings with another game (Battle Chef Brigade) which was downloaded from the e-shop to the SD card.  **I'm wondering now if this error is (at least sometimes) caused by problems with the SD card slot.**  So, to anyone who has this issue and a simple reboot doesn't help, make sure the game is installed on the system's HD instead of an SD card and see if that helps.